# Blazor modify validation message

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

I want to modify a validation message (Replace property name with localized name) for a model property. I use Blazored/FluentValidation library. The property is bound with mud-blazor.

I tried the mud-blazor Validation attribute, but it doesn't seem to fire the Func I passed. Also there seems no way to actually replace the message.

Then I tried to use the EditContext. But there it only seems possible to get all the messages without modifying them. The ValidationMessageStore created with this EditContext also doesn't contain any messages, although there clearly are messages in the UI.

Is there a way to modify validation messages before they are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The EditForm component can bind to a model that uses DataAnnotations.  Each data annotation can have a custom error message.

Short example, as taken from from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

In ExampleComponent.razor:

```
<EditForm Model="@exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

In ExampleModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ExampleModel
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Please provide a name.")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

When hitting any button inside the EditForm, with `type="submit"`, the validation will trigger and display the appropriate messages inside the `<ValidationSummary>`, as well as each `<ValidationMessage>` component.

Comment: I need to show a different message in the UI than defined on the model. One reason is, the validators for fluent validation are not necessarily in the same project as the ui and the translations. Also you might have the requirement to show a totally different message, which contains more information about the context.
In angular it was possible to get all the errors for a property in the ui, and show a custom message. But with blazor there doesn't seem to be a "ModelState" where I can get and change messages.